# asp menu control not looking properly in view page source from browser

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem with asp menu control. I want to display my menu orientation as horizontal. It is looking fine when i debug, but when i see the viewsource of my page it is displaying vertically and my sub items also displaying. See the below two images how my menu is displaying when i debug and after view source from browser

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17203514/1.JPG]

[image: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/17203514/2.JPG]

also why it is showing skipnavigation links when i view source? I dont have nothing in my page except the menu control.

Comment: Your question is confusing... What do you mean by "when i see the viewsource of my page it is displaying vertically and my sub items also displaying"? If you are looking at the source, you aren't looking at any display! We will not be able to help you unless you post the code that you are using to generate these menus.

Comment: sorry for not properly explaining.In my asp page except menu control nothing is there. When i execute my page it will display like above first image.Then in browser i right click it and say view page source and then saved it as html and opened again in browser.Then it is displaying like the second image above. my question is why it is displaying vertically even i set orientation horizontal? and another why it is showing skip navigation links?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the `ShowStartingNode` of your `SiteMapDataSource` to `false`?

Comment: menu control didnt have property called ShowStartingNode

Comment: True, the `ShowStartingNode` is in `SiteMapDataSource`, just as I've said.